# Trello API: determine when a card changed lists?

Tags: trello, api, reporting

I'm considering the feasibility of doing simple reporting on Trello data. My quick review of the API documentation has left me with a question.

Can I use the Trello API to determine when a given card (part of a given board) changed lists?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you get the [actions list](https://trello.com/docs/api/card/index.html#get-1-cards-card-id-actions) for a card, and filter it to only include updates to the idList, something like this:

```
GET /1/cards/4f429d592aa6beb467155e9a/actions?filter=updateCard:idList
             ^ replace with card id ^
```

... then you can examine the `date` field on the returned actions to determine when the card changed lists.

Comment: I'm getting an "invalid value for filter" for  

`GET /1/cards/4f54ed97354bce507c1c51f0/actions?filter=updateCard:4f439d5087f6beb467148e71&key=<key>&token=<token>`  

And as far as I can see the id is a valid list id.

Comment: Oh, you don't need to put the actual list id; you literally put `filter=updateCard:idList`

Comment: Also -- don't forget that a card can change lists multiple times.  I suggest grouping by id and sorting by date.

Answer (score 0):

Just to back up @Daniel LeCheminant; that'll work.  I typically would use the actions list completely on a single card and then find where I see a list change.  In my use with Trello sometimes I would ask for something similar and it would skip over certain things.  I had to use "listAfter" to see who last touched a card because the admin would actually be the last to touch it since only he could put it in the archive list.  So I found the person who touched it before he did; just as an example of the data coming back a bit 'off'.

Feel free to message me if you have any more questions  I built a complete spreadsheet with charts etc for the development team at Tealium.  So I am quite familiar with the API and Google Script